# Matplotlib contourplot fails when no contour exists

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I use the cookbook example frin http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data to make contourplots. However some of my data may just contain zeros, in which case I get an ValueError:zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import uniform, seed


# make up some randomly distributed data
seed(1234)
npts = 200
x = uniform(-2,2,npts)
y = uniform(-2,2,npts)
z = 0*x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2) #Here i multiply by zero
# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,100)
yi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,100)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

#zi[0][0]=0.00001 would make everything ok again
print(zi)
# do the plotting and save the result
CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
plt.show()
```

Is there an elegant way to deal with this? 
Is this worthy of a ticket in matplotlib?

Comment: How would you like the code to behave? You are providing bad data, you get an exception. Sounds fine to me.

Comment: Well I would not say that I'm providing "bad" data. z = 0*x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2) + 0.0000001, works and contains as much information.

Comment: However after using griddata to do the interpolation with the above code you are getting a set of NaNs rather than a set of 0s or other numbers which is "bad" in the sense that it is difficult to decide how that should be used in a contour plot. Throwing an exception seems like a reasonable response.

Comment: @Tommy correct I noticed the NaN's when I was trying to make the example (my original code produced arrays of zeros from a csv file). Interestingly plt.contour can deal with the NaNs as long as not all are NaN, (take away the *0), but it can't deal with this if _all_ elements are a zero. That is the only time when I run into this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just catch the exception, ie:

```
try:
    CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
    plt.show()
except ValueError:
    print("Can't plot this data")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my current workaround was:         if numpy.max(zi)==numpy.min(zi)==0:
            zi[0][0]=0.00000001, because i would still like a plot. There is something more elegant about the exception handling.